# Creating a wrapper template component and injecting an inner components template

Tags: angular

I would like to create a template component wrapper that will wrap my custom templates.

I need this to be a component since I wan't to inject things and do some logic inside.

This is a simple example my component with the hello wrapper:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template:
  `<hello><div>This is my component</div></hello>`
})
export class MyComponent{}
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
<div>
  <div>hello component intro</div>
  <div>This is my component</div> <!-- This is the injection I'm looking for -->
  <div>hello component outro</div>
</div>
```

Hello component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template:
   `<div>
      <div>hello component intro</div>
         #####Inject here#####
      <div>hello component outro</div>
   </div>`
})
export class HelloComponent{}
```

Is there any way I can inject the template into a wrapper component?

I'm using Angular version 6 if that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What you are looking for is `Content Projection`.

Just use `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the component where you want to inject the content dynamically.

### hello.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template:
   `<div>
      <div>hello component intro</div>
         <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- CONTENT WILL BE ADDED HERE -->
      <div>hello component outro</div>
   </div>`
})
export class HelloComponent{}
```

### Usages

```
<hello>
  <div>This is my component</div> <!-- This is the injection I'm looking for -->
</hello>
```

### It will produce

```
<div>
  <div>hello component intro</div>
  <div>This is my component</div> <!-- This is the injection I'm looking for -->
  <div>hello component outro</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can remove the `<hello>` DOM element?

Comment: There is no such option from Angular yet however it could be done through the Dynamic Component Injection.

Comment: I understand. BTW, will this work recursively for more than one level of components?